# JRenderer and JQuery Mobile List View Losing Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm doing a pretty typical JSON request and populating a JRendere template.  It works great, but when I wrap the li in a href it loses all formatting.

HTML Code:

```
<script id="recipeTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 

                {{for Content}}
                <a href='searchResults.html' data-transition='slide'>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c" style='height: 150px; border: 0px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;'>
                        <img src="{{:ImageURL}}" style='max-height: 125px; max-width: 125px;  position: absolute;'/>
                         <div style='margin-left: 50px;'>
                             <h3  style="white-space : normal;">{{:Title}}</h3>
                             <h3  style="white-space : normal;">Ratings:</h3>
                             <p style="white-space : normal;">{{:Description}}</p>
                        </div>

                </li>
                </a>
                {{/for}}
        </script>
```

The JS is as follows:

```
$("#search").focusout(function()
{
    var searchTerm = $("#search").val();
    $.getJSON("http://website?searchterm=" + searchTerm + "&callback=?",
    function (data)
    {
        var htmlString = $("#recipeTemplate").render( data );
        $('#results').html(htmlString).listview('refresh');
    });
});
```

[image: error]

It looks as above.  Why does it lose the CSS?

Thanks, Graeme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works great, but when I wrap the li in a href it loses all
>   formatting.

First of all, having an `<li>` within an `<a>` tag is invalid HTML.

Your CSS is most likely relying on a specific order, targeting an element then maybe another element which has to have a specific class inside that element, and so on.

By adding the `<a>` around the `<li>` element you have now changed the expected order and you CSS is not able any more to match the selectors.

Placing your `<a>` tag inside the `<li>` instead could keep the CSS intact and at the same time be valid HTML, well, assuming you have `ul` or `ol` around the set of `li`'s in the final HTML.

Check your CSS and make sure you are not messing with the expected order of nested elements or classes. Then either ass the `<a>` so it doesn't break the CSS or update the CSS to match your new hierarchy.